# Error while writing dataframe into avro format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a dataframe from hive table using `spark sql` having avro format.
I want to write this dataframe in another hive table whose format is avro, but I get the below error.

Can you please help me with the issue.

**Spark shell command:**

```
./spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0
```

**The code:**

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._

df4.write
.mode("append").partitionBy("country")
.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
.save("/user/XYZ/AVRO1/")
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[Stage 1:====================================================>  (191 + 2) / 200]18/07/10 12:33:40 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.OutputWriterFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/OutputWriter;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:428)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1345)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/07/10 12:33:40 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.OutputWriterFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/OutputWriter;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:428)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1345)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/07/10 12:33:40 WARN FileOutputCommitter: Could not delete hdfs://prism-0.xor-ind.xoriant.com:8020/user/sanket/AVRO1/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201807101233_0001_m_000031_0
18/07/10 12:33:40 ERROR DynamicPartitionWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201807101233_0001_m_000031_0 aborted.
18/07/10 12:33:40 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 31.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 195)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.OutputWriterFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/OutputWriter;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:428)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1345)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:438)
        ... 8 more
18/07/10 12:33:40 WARN FileOutputCommitter: Could not delete hdfs://prism-0.xor-ind.xoriant.com:8020/user/sanket/AVRO1/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201807101233_0001_m_000001_0
18/07/10 12:33:40 ERROR DynamicPartitionWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201807101233_0001_m_000001_0 aborted.
18/07/10 12:33:40 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 194)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.OutputWriterFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/OutputWriter;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:428)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1345)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:438)
        ... 8 more
18/07/10 12:33:40 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 194, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.OutputWriterFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/OutputWriter;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:428)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1345)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:438)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. instead of giving format and save, directly use `avro`

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
df4
.write
.mode("append").partitionBy("country")
.avro("/user/XYZ/AVRO1/")
```

Comment: Hi Chitral, I tried but I am getting the same error.

Comment: use this:
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-avro_2.11/4.0.0/spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar

and then spark-shell --jars spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar

Comment: I also faced this issue and adding libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "4.0.0" resolved it